# Using JSch to access an SSH Server which is controlled by a Gateway Server

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, gateway

I was successful in using the JSch library in accessing an SSH Server directly but I am having troubles with accessing the SSH Server which is controlled by a Gateway Server. Have anybody encountered this issue yet? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "controlled by a Gateway Server"? Could you describe in detail what the software has to do to connect to the target?

Comment: @Kenster The Gateway Server is used to connect to the SSH Server. I need to connect to the gateway server and send scripts that will be executed in the SSH Server. Formerly, I used the JSch library to execute scripts directly to the SSH Server, but now the Gateway Server complicated it. Thanks

Comment: I tried this one but did not work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770019/how-to-ssh-to-a-server-behind-another-ssh-server-using-jsch

Comment: How would you be connecting to the gateway server? How about from the gateway server to the final server?

Comment: @Kenster Normally, I connect to the gateway server using Putty then I enter ssh <server> then it connects to the final server. I am having troubles integrating it in Java using JSch

Comment: @PhilipMorris you're not alone... I think this library is defunct.