# SSH to a linux box and tunnel to another linux box from here using SUDO command as a different user

Tags: ssh, proxy, jsch, portforwarding, tunnel

I am able to connect to a linux box using Jsch. Now i need to tunnel/ssh to another linux box from here by doing a SUDO as a different user who has priviledges. I saw one post to use PROXYSSH class ([How to SSH to a server behind another SSH server using JSch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770019/how-to-ssh-to-a-server-behind-another-ssh-server-using-jsch)) but i do not see any such class here (http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you run `sudo -u <other username> echo hi` does it work, or does it ask you for a password you don't have?