# How to ssh multiple times by JSch: port forwarding, ssh command or SSH tunnel?

Tags: ssh, tcp, jsch, tunnel

By terminal I am able to SSH multiple times to connect to the server:

(client--->gateway--->server1---->server2---)

But now to do it through JSch library of Java, how to go about it?
First tried portforwarding, but on terminal I am not doing that (not setting `-R -L` parameters in `ssh`).

Then I came across question [How to SSH to a server behind another SSH server using JSch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6770019/850848), but I don't understand how to create tcp tunnel!