# How to use paramiko to SSH

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have built below simple python code to connect to one of my webserver.

```
import paramiko

# Set up SSH client
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# Set up connection details
ip = "10.218.16.16"
user = "user1"
password = "234!!!lem600@HW"

# Connect to server
try:
    ssh.connect(ip, username=user, password=password)
    print(f"Successfully logged in as {ssh.exec_command('whoami')[1].read().decode().strip()}")

except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException:
    print("Authentication failed")
    
except paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException:
    print("Unable to establish SSH connection")
    
finally:
    ssh.close()
```

This works fine.
After connecting to this webserver, I am performing below steps in putty.

1. ssh user2@hadoopc1h1
2. Entering the password -235!!!lem600@HW

so what I need is to do the above also in same code...
I have added below part also..

```
ip2 = "hadoopc1h1"
user2 = "user2"
password2 = "235!!!lem600@HW"


try:
    # Execute ssh command to connect to second server
    _, stdout, _ = ssh1.exec_command(f'ssh {user2}@{ip2}')

   
    stdin = stdout.channel.makefile("wb")
    stdin.write(f"{password2}\n".encode())
    stdin.flush()

    # Print output of ssh command to second server
    print(stdout.read().decode())
```

Here what I am getting

```
OSError: Socket is closed
```

Network connectivity is also available...can someone help me?

Comment: `exec_command` executes a single command and closes the connection. You need to `invoke_shell()` to get an interactive shell where you can continue to enter commands. For instance: `remote_connection = ssh1.invoke_shell()` then execute commands like: `remote_connection.send("command")`

Comment: note: no matter if you are using private or public IP, if the login/password you posted is your real one then I'd immediately rotate the password and consider this pair compromised (in case you use the same l/p elsewhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tying to automate an interactive shell is usually wrong approach and will cause you troubles. Your attempt with `exec_command` is definitely a better start. See also
[Providing input/subcommands to command executed over SSH with JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42997422/850848)

Though you might be actually looking for
[How to SSH to a server behind another SSH server using JSch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6770019/850848)

Answer (score 0):

@Cow is right.

Once you invoke a shell, you have to execute a sleep command as well to ensure the command sent was executed before going to the next command.

```
time.sleep(1) //sleep for 1 sec
```

Moreover, it is required to send "\n" at the end of the every command you send.
Example:

```
remote_connection.send("command\n")
```

All together it should look like this if two commands are sending.

```
remote_connection.send("command\n")
time.sleep(1)
remote_connection.send("command\n")
time.sleep(1)
```